# Why when type command to run a program, auto insert ./ at previous of program name?

Tags: bash, go

For example,

```golang
package main

import (
   "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func hello(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(res, "Hello, my name is Inigo Montoya")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:4000", nil)
}
```

[image]

When type command , Why not `inigo` , auto convert to `./inigo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
./inigo
```

because `.` is not, and it should not be, in your `PATH`. `.` just refers to the current directory.

Assuming you are using `bash`, as the label to the question suggests, this alternative

```
$PWD/inigo
```

would also work as well as any other relative or absolute path to `inigo`.

#### edit

Alternative, you can add `$PWD` to your `PATH` which will have the advantage of not requiring you to type any of the above without having the security implications of adding `.`.

Let's say you are in the directory that contains `inigo`, then

```
PATH+=:$PWD
```

and then just type

```
inigo
```

from anywhere.

Comment: "because . is not, and it should not be, in your PATH" - in general, yes. In some projects I do push `.` to `PATH` with `direnv`. Saves me the pain of typing `./` every time I use local binaries/scripts in those projects.